# $_SESSION variables - does session_start() have any impact?

Tags: php, session-variables

There are cases, that some functions use `session_start()` early (mostly, plugins in CMS platforms).

I have a question - does a starting of session might affect something negatively  in a whole application/CMS?

I ask this because I remember that calling similar functions (like `ob_start()`, `ob_end()` or etc..) MATTERS, and I wanted to know if same applies to `session` functions too, if they have any NEGATIVE impact in a global scope.  ( i am mostyle interested only in negative impacts).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks! p.s.  if you had posted that as answer, i could have rated you.   p.s.2. if session is already started, then firing `session_start()` causes any problems?  p.s.3. i know what you mean, it will be pointless. but you havent mentioned about negative sides - are there any?

Comment: Posted it as an answer and addressed your other two questions.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks! now you can remove the comment, as it is duplicate .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `session_start()`, any changes to any sessions will be lost when the request is done, unless your system is set up to auto start sessions. Using sessions without starting would simply be kind of pointless.

The important part is to check if sessions already are started or not before calling `session_start()`. If it already is started, you would get warnings saying "session already started".
One way of doing this is using `session_status()` like this:

```
if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    // Session isn't started, let's start it.
    session_start();
}
```

There aren't really any negative impact from starting sessions, unless some library/extension are using sessions in some very unorthodox way (but that could be said for anything, really).